# Can't reliably ping network printer

Tags: network-printer

Very strange problem with a networked Brother MFC9140-CDN printer.

Some PCs on the network can reliably ping the printer which is on 10.0.0.203, however the majority of PCs sometimes get a response from the printer and other times get a timeout. In "Devices and Printers" you can sit and watch the printer change from Online to Offline and back again every so often, the majority of the time it is offline but occasionally for no apparent reason it will work for a while.

Comment: Have you checked the cable, or, if using Wi-Fi, the signal strenght? This may be the problem.

Comment: I don't believe it's the cable on the basis that some users can print and ping ok, I've also tried connecting the printer on a different cable+socket. None of the users are printing using WiFi.

Comment: In addition to the previous suggestion from @redbeam_ , I also recommend you to check if the IP address could be duplicated.

Comment: What are the differences between the PCs that connect and those that don't? Location, cabling, software, drivers?